# How to add service worker to Vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js, service-worker

I'm trying to use a service worker in my Vue.js project. I have it functioning with a very basic worker that I just dropped into my `public/` directory (example below), but this doesn't allow me to load dependencies using `require()`, which is what I'd like to do next.

```js
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log(self)
});

self.addEventListener('fetch',  function(event) {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  console.log(url)
})
```

I found [service-worker-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-worker-loader), but it presents me with this during compilation: `Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlink' of null`. The error persists even when I provide a `serviceWorker.js` file that is completely blank. My `vue.config.js` has the loader configured:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /serviceWorker\.js$/, use: { loader: "service-worker-loader" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm referencing my worker using `import registerServiceWorker from 'service-worker-loader!./serviceWorker';`.

Am I missing something basic? What's the "standard" way to include custom service worker code into a Vue.js project?